# sql-server jdbc4 drivers doesn't list all columns?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a (sql server) column which have a **System Type** but no **Data Type** (It is actually more then one). Using the Microsoft jdbc4 drivers and trying to list all the columns using metadata for this table this column with the missing Data type doesn't show up:

```
ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null,"schema","tableName", null);
while (rs.next()) {
    String column = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
    System.out.println("column:" + column); // This will not print the column
}
```

If you use the odbc drivers, in for example C#, it does show up (The column with the missing Data Type). And if this column is a constraint it will show up when using the the jdbc api for listing all constraints:

```
ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getIndexInfo(null, 
                                                     "schema", 
                                                     "tableName", 
                                                      true/*list unique*/, 
                                                      true);
while(rs.next()){
    String column = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
    System.out.println("column:" + column); // This will print the column, if it is a unique constraint.
}
```

This behavior is the same regardless if you use jdbc4 drivers or the jtds drivers.

So my question is, if this is a bug or is it something that I'm missing? And Is it possible to list the meta data in an other way to get all the columns for table?

To create a Table which doesn't display a Data Type. This demands that you create a user which haven't read access to the user defined Data Types. This is how can reproduce it:

I found this code [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2983/security-for-sql-server-user-defined-data-types/)

```
CREATE TYPE TEST_TYPE2 FROM [int] NOT NULL
GO
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    CustomerID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    LastName    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FirstName   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ZIP         TEST_TYPE2 NOT NULL
)
GO
-- Create Table without UDDT
CREATE TABLE Customer_Orig
(
    CustomerID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    LastName    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FirstName   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ZIP         INT NOT NULL
)
GO

-- Create User with db_datareader to database
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN testUser WITH PASSWORD=N'THE_PASSWORD', 
 DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
 CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE TEST_DATABASE
GO
CREATE USER testUser FOR LOGIN testUser 
GO
USE TEST_DATABASE
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'THE_PASSWORD'
GO
```

I understand why it doesn't show up, but I way does it work for the odbc drivers?

Comment: With "jdbc4" driver you mean the Microsoft driver, right? (Because *jdbc4* is just a version of the JDBC specs). Could you provide a `CREATE TABLE` statement for one of those tables?

Comment: Yes I mean the Microsoft drivers. Regarding the CREATE TABLE statement, I'm trying to do that right now and I'll add that to the question as soon as I can. But this is a production server which I'm testing on so I don't really have it right now.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: did you try `"%"` instead of `null` for the last parameter in the `getColumns()` call?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but with no success